# Why should a python google cloud function not contain a Pipfile?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

According to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python)

> Dependency specification using the Pipfile/Pipfile.lock standard is currently not supported. Your project should not include these files.

I use Pipfile for managing my dependencies and create a requirements.txt file through

> pipenv lock --requirements

Till now everything works and my gcloud function is up and running. So why should a python google cloud function not contain a Pipfile?

If it shouldn't contain, what is the preferred way suggested to manage an isolated environment ?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your function, you deploy it on its own environment. You won't manage several environment because the cloud function deployment is dedicated to one and only one piece of code.

That's why, it's useless to have a virtual environment in a single usage environment. You could use Cloud Run to do that because you can customize your build and runtime environment. But, here again, it's useless: You won't have concurrent environment in the same container, it does not make sense.

Comment: it's useful for me on my computer when developing stuff. Different python projects could have different versions of dependencies and i work with pipenv to seperate between this environments. I understand why pipfile is not respected by cloud functions build pack but why it is forbidden to have a Pipfile ? Why is it different from a txt file which is just ignored